# Python: How to read in multiple CSV files fromfolder names stored in a list

Tags: python, pandas, arguments

I have a function "read" that I want to use to read in multiple CSVs. It looks something like this.

```
def read(year)
    file_path = working_dir + "\\" + year + "\\mycsv.csv"
    df = pd.dataframe(pd.read_csv(file_path)
    return df
```

All the files have the same working_dir and the same mycsv.csv names. The only difference between them is the "year" folder name. I have all the years required stored in a dictionary "run_years", and I'd like to run the read function multiple times to read all the CSVs I have in all the "year" folders. What's the best way to do this?

I tried running a function like

```
for x in run_years
    run_years = x
    read(x)
```

But this gave me a TypeError message, for trying to concatinate a list with a string. Connverting to a string resulted in the list be read in as one unit.

Comment: You should consider using the `os` module for file paths. It provides methods to loop over files/folders also. Can you share a sample of the json with "run_years"?

Comment: If you are going to parse all the files in the given folder, what @amanb suggested is a better approach. Coming to the error, as it is a datatype error sharing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will enable us to help you in a better way. If you want a quick and dirty fix, try using `file_path = f'{workdir}\{year}\mycsv.csv'
`

Answer (score 0):

**To the Error Message you recieved:**

In short, the current code is trying to combine a list item with a string, likely in the line below:

```
file_path = working_dir + "\\" + year + "\\mycsv.csv"
```

To that end, the `year` value is likely being supplied to the function as a list item, instead of a single string

**To get started:**

You mention that you have all the target `year` values in a dictionary called `run_years`.

When iterating over your dictionary, it looks like you might have a typo here:

```
for x in run_years:
    run_years = x
    read(x)
```

In a way, your code is saying to iterate over each dictionary key item `x` in your dictionary `run_years`

But in the next line, you set your dictionary `run_years` equal to the single key value `x` from that dictionary

Consider revising like below (*Note - From your code provided, I'm not sure if the years value is in the dictionary key, or value*):

```
for key, value in run_years: #For each key, value pair in your dictionary run_years
    read(key) #run your function on the key value - swap to read(value) if that matches your use case
```

That should run your `read()` function on each target item in your `run_years` dictionary